# tvOS UITableView cell focused

Tags: uitableview, tvos

I'm searching for a callback function of `UITableView` when the row is focused for when I navigate with apple remote and press up or down to select the row (not when I press enter).

On iOS we have `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` thats called when user selects the row but I can't find the function that is called when user navigates in the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
     //this gives you the indexpath of the focused cell
     NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
}
```

then you can do whatever you want with it in that function

Answer (score 1):

Testing this in mid-2019, nextFocusedIndexPath does not seem to be available from the context object anymore. But it wasn't too hard to work around:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
  let cell = context.nextFocusedView as! UITableViewCell
  let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to do something with last one selected, you can do that like this

```
NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath = [context previouslyFocusedIndexPath];

UITableViewCell *nextCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
UILabel *nextTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[nextCell viewWithTag:100];
nextTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UITableViewCell *prevCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath];
UILabel *prevTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[prevCell viewWithTag:100];
prevTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```